# Is template name always same as directory name?

Tags: templates

When creating child theme, I must write like this.

```
/*
Theme Name: 2012 Child
Template: twentytwelve
*/
```

Is that `Template` name is always same as directory name?
Or is it defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

> The Template is the directory name of the parent theme
>
> ...
> If you want to make a child of a theme with the directory name
> example-theme-name, then you would use Template: example-theme-name.

So yes its always the name of the parent theme directory.